# I get NaN value when i try to get my latitude and longitude value from a mqtt channel? I try to parse them to float but still end up with a NaN value

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, mqtt, esp8266

I've tried to Parse my GPS longitude and latitude to float so the my googlemap can read it but it only return `NaN`. 
I send the data as float from my arduino via the mqtt channel which my html code is reading the data from does anyone perhaps no why it fails?

```js
window.initialize = initialize;

var redraw = function(payload) {
    lat = parseFloat(payload.message.lat);
    lng = parseFloat(payload.message.lng);

    console.log(lng);

    map.setCenter({ lat: 59.3559, lng:lng, alt: 0 });
    mark.setPosition({ lat: 59.3559, lng:lng, alt: 0 });

    lineCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(59.3559,lng));
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Let us see your payload.message!

Comment: Why are using parsing the lat long twice?

Comment: Please edit your title. It's not helpful for people who want to search your question

Comment: seems payload.message.lat and .lng are not even close to being numbers ... either undefined, or maybe an object ... what does `payload.message` look like if you output it to the browsers developer tools console

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59280509/edit) the question to show your `onMessageArrived` function so we can see exactly how you are processing the incoming message. The most likely cause is that the payload is still a string and needs parsing to a JSON object

Comment: I send the message in arduino with this format in " sprintf(msg, lng: "%f", lng); " and i get this output from the browser: i put the link to the picture up there at the post!

Comment: But when i use this format instead "  sprintf(msg, "{lng: %f}", lng); " the message output in the browser is ---> message: "{lng: 18.873501}"

Comment: In future please EDIT the question to add details. Also please do not post screenshots of errors, post the actual text and format it properly. Images are impossible to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the message payload is received as a string (MQTT messages are just byte arrays, it's up to the user to convert them to/from any higher level format).

If you want to use the string `"{lng: 18.873501}"` as a JSON object `{ "lng": 18.873501 }` you need to parse it first.

Since you haven't supplied the `onMessageArrived` function it's difficult to suggest how to fix this properly, but you can do the following:

```
var location = JSON.parse(message.payload);
var lat = location.lat;
var lng = location.lng;
```